# Can i add javascript in xml file where xml file has <svg> tag

Tags: javascript, svg

Can i use javascript in xml file which has `<svg>` tag. I mean
file name is **hello.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
```

Please help me on this

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you will need to wrap javascript in CDATA section. Example

```
<svg>
<script>
<![CDATA[
function()
{
    any code........
}
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

CDATA (unparsed character data) is required in this case because javascript's < and & characters are illegal in XML.

XML parser ignores everything inside CDATA section.

Comment: Also note that declaring the svg namespace is required if you want the elements to be svg elements and not plain xml elements.

Comment: thanks....but i have tried a alert(); statement in the function you mentioned above but where should i use that function....please help me on this.......

Comment: You should use the function wherever you want to use it.

Comment: You don't actually have to wrap the content in a CDATA section. You can use character references instead (e.g. `<` to `&lt;`) or not use `<` and `&` in the script.

Comment: actually what i did is i have used <svg> tag and developed something ...but what i neeed is can i write jsp scriplets bet <svg> </svg> tags...i mean <svg> <% any java code %> </svg>....please help me on this

Comment: @jazgot I want to add the javascript file into xml file.
Can you help me to write the code to add the javascript file to xml file?